# UINavigationController navigationBarHidden

Tags: objective-c, ios

Hey everbody, i'm having problem with a simple question.

I have a NavigationController, 01.xib ans 02.xib. 
I set in IB NavigationController to dont display the navigationBar. Well, when i go to 02.xib, i set it to appear.

```
[self navigationController].navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

Everything works fine.

But, when i come back to 01.xib with the top button, the bar still appearing in the 01.xib.

How can i fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in first view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is happening because they are referencing the same navigation controller.

You could set it hidden again in the viewDidAppear method of your 01 class.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self navigationController].navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```